# Function of % symbol in SQL for Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am wondering what would this code mean in the context of a table called webpages, with the following fields; (pagetitle, content, author, URL, links, #linkto). Replies greatly appreciated. The code is -
WHERE place LIKE %New York% 
ORDER BY #linkto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard characters to use in a LIKE query against an Access database depend on two factors. If

1. the query is run from within Microsoft Access itself, and
2. the database has **not** been configured to use "SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)"

then the wildcard characters are

- `*` (zero or more characters), and
- `?` (one character).

In all other cases the wildcard characters are the more common `%` and `_`, respectively, as it appears to be in your particular case.

Answer (score 2):

It is a mistake.  In most databases (and the standard), `%` is a wildcard character (for `LIKE`) that matches zero or more characters.  In MS Access, the equivalent character is `*`, so the code would be:

```
WHERE place LIKE "*New York*"
```

In other words, in Access, `%` is the percent character.

Comment: re: "It is a mistake." - Not necessarily. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27207943/2144390) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It is a wildcard, like (*) character.

Picks out any "place" that has "New York" in its value. Doesn't matter what is before or what follows it.